# Crontab | Missing Python Module

Tags: python, cron

I'm very new to Unix and crontab. The only major issue I'm running into is pointing terminal to the python modules for the specific program I'm trying to run. From command line the program runs fine but won't from crontab.

The first cronjob sends me an email saying that the cronjob is running. The second(createUpdate) runs a script I've built, set to run each minute.

crontab -l returns:

```
*/1 * * * * python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/emailalert.py
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH =/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages; export PYTHONPATH; python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

Am I structuring PYTHONPATH correctly?

Should I break it out before the cron?

Is 'export PYTHONPATH' necessary?

**EDIT**
I forgot to add the error

```
/bin/sh: PYTHONPATH: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py", line 1, in <module>
    import beatbox
ImportError: No module named beatbox
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The right way would be

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

Please be aware of spaces in variable assignment.  No semicolon and no need to export variables, since declaring them before the commands already makes them active for the command itself.

Comment: When I was using sudo crontab, some python modules were missing. Showing path to "site-packages" directory with PYTHONPATH did the trick. Just in case someone faces the similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

in your crontab. No semi-colons, `PYTHONPATH` only applies to that instance of `python` and your script.

(Further, I think you got the

```
/bin/sh: PYTHONPATH: command not found
```

error because you have a space between `PYTHONPATH` and the equal sign.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export PYTHONPATH.  If you installed beatbox globally, you should be able to include the environment setting on the same line(in the same command) as the call to Python, like this:

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

Also, make sure there aren't any spaces between the variable name, the equal sign and the value of the variable.

You should really be using `virtualenv` to create a sandboxed Python, so you don't have to install external libraries globally.  If you install virtualenv and install your dependencies into it, you will be able to do something like this

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/virtual/env/bin/python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

and not worry about global dependencies.

Here are the docs for virtualenv: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

```
*/1 * * * * pip install beatbox && python /Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/createUpdate.py
```

had a hard time to find a working solution and end up with this.